# Get Order details in other page

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order, frontend

In My account page i create Cancel. If user click cancel it redirect to next page On that page How i get current order details like Order id amount etc

```
<?php if (!$_order->hasInvoices()) {?>
<span class="separator">|</span>                                
<a href="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl().'cancel-order'; ?>" class="link-reorder"><?php echo $this->__('Cancel') ?></a>
<?php }?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can send order id in param

```
  <?php if (!$_order->hasInvoices()) {?>
    <span class="separator">|</span>                                
    <a href="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl().'cancel-order?ref='.$_order->getIncrementId(); ?>" class="link-reorder"><?php echo $this->__('Cancel') ?></a><?php }?>
```

Comment: I have phtml how to get that phtml file

Comment: `Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('ref');` you can get it with this code

Comment: i try to echo this but no output <?php echo Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('ref');?>

Comment: did the param showing in url?

Comment: yes domain.com/cancel-order?ref100002375

Comment: it should be <a href="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl().'cancel-order?ref='.<?php echo $_order->getIncrementId() ?>; ?>" class="link-reorder"><?php echo $this->__('Cancel') ?></a><?php }?>

Comment: @ParasSood you find the mistake but not corrected properly :P

Comment: i already changed but phtml i didn't get

Comment: @LearningMagento update the answer there was `=` missing

Comment: Thanks it's working can you please give me examble of simple form submit controller